# Redis RDB persistence issue

Tags: redis

I faced a strange issue with my ethercalc sheets, from time to time I remarked that my sheets were evicted automatically.In my redis configuration,  I use an:

- RDB persistence mode
- TTL set to -1 by default
- "maxmemory" sets to 0 (no limitation).

Any idea please ?

Comment: When you say "ttl to -1 by default", did you set any value for this in your config file?

Comment: @PascalLeMerrer No